# What are the very specific advantages to WebJars compared to simply using Bower?

Tags: webjars

I am new to WebJars and so far have failed to see any real advantages that they bring to the table compared to simply using Bower for example. What justifies the idea of putting frontend JS into backend JARs?

Please name at least one or more "**objective**" advantages to using WebJars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebJars are useful when you have a JVM-based project and you want to use only one dependency manager / build tool.